# Is the Wasserstein distance the same down a Markov chain?

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory, lipschitz-functions, optimal-transport, information-geometry

For two Markov chains:

$$X \rightarrow f(X)$$
$$Y \rightarrow f(Y)$$

where $f$ is 1-Lipschitz, if one minimizes the Wasserstein distance between $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$, does this result in the minimization of the Wasserstein distance between $X$ and $Y$?

The intuition is that this is correct since for a 1-Lipschitz function, the distance $D_A(f(X), f(Y)) \leq D_B(X, Y)$, i.e. the distance between $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ is at most the distance between $X$ and $Y$ in another metric space, but I don't know how I could exactly prove this other than use some heuristic.

Any further intuition/ideas/proofs would be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Explain your notation, please:  in what way is $X\to f(X)$ a Markov chain?

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, it is a Markov chain as it satisfies the Markov property, where $f(X)$ is only conditionally dependent on X. We also have $Y$ as a random variable that is sampled from another distribution.

Comment: What are the parameters over which you want to minimize the Wasserstein distance?